# How to re-serialize a modified object and insert back into an XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, linq-to-xml

I have a nested set of objects represented in an XDocument as such:

```
<Record xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="FooInfo">
  <Name>Red</Name>
  <Record xsi:type="BarInfo">
    <Name>Tomato</Name>
    <Record xsi:type="BazInfo">
      <Name>Juice</Name>
    </Record >
    <Record xsi:type="BazInfo">
      <Name>Sauce</Name>
    </Record >
  </Record >
</Record >
```

I query the `_doc.Descendents()` and deserialize to the object `BazInfo`:

```
 var info = doc.Descendants().Where(d => d.Attributes(xn).FirstOrDefault() != null)
                             .Where(d => d.Attribute(xn).Value == "BazInfo")
                             .Where(d => d.Element(name).Value == "Sauce");

 int count = info .Count();

 var e = info.First();
 BazInfo bi = (BazInfo)s.Deserialize(e.CreateReader());
```

The BazInfo class looks like:

```
class BazInfo : IInfo {  
    [XmlElement]
    string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement]
    string Manufacturer { get; set; }
}
```

When `BazInfo` is initially serialized, the `Manufacturer` property was not included - i.e. no `<Manufacturer />` element - because no value has been assigned. That isn't a problem except that when I want to assign a value, I can't just look up that element in the descendents or elements collections. So, I deserialize the object and assign the value:

```
bi.Manufacturer = "Acme"; 
// re-serialize element
s.Serialize(e.CreateWriter(), bi);
```

When I try to re-serialize the object, I receive an exeption:

> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the
>   XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException:
>   WriteStartDocument cannot be called on writers created with
>   ConformanceLevel.Fragment.

I want to be able to insert the object back where it belongs:

```
  <Record xsi:type="BarInfo">
    <Name>Tomato</Name>
    <Record xsi:type="BazInfo">
      <Name>Juice</Name>
    </Record >
    <Record xsi:type="BazInfo">
      <Name>Sauce</Name>
      <Manufacturer>Acme</Manufacturer>
    </Record >
  </Record >
```

Any ideas?

I know I could add an element "Manufacturer" if not found and then assign the value, but that seems like it could get broken easily.